# How to implement load more posts with Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-limitto

**In AngularJS I used Limit To, but on the Angular2 this function was removed.**

*Example:*

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in travel.cruise | limitTo:travel.limit"      class="cruises">
  ....Content here...
</div>
```

*Controller:*

```
app.controller('TravelController', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.cruise = cruises;
  vm.limit = 3;

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var increamented = vm.limit + 3;
    vm.limit = incremented > vm.cruise.length ? vm.cruise.length :    increamented;
  };
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? This sounds like a simple task: incrementing a limit, and taking the N first elements of an array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to think of it as a function. Take a look at this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of getItems(items, limit)">
</div>
```

`getItems` may apply caching to prevent multiple requests.

Or if the array is not lazy loaded. Try this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:limit">
</div>
```